# In Warhammer 40K does taking a Chaos Icon replace other weapons?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The Codex for Chaos Space Marines says on the data sheet for Chaos Space Marines

```
One model may take a Chaos Icon (pg 153).
```

Does taking a Chaos Icon replace the model's boltgun?  Can the model with the Chaos Icon replace his boltgun with a chainsword and still have that with an Icon of Chaos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does taking a Chaos Icon replace the model's boltgun?

No.

> Can the model with the Chaos Icon replace his boltgun with a chainsword and still have that with an Icon of Chaos?

Yes. If a piece of wargear has to be swapped it will specifically say as much in the war gear entry. If it just says `X models can take Y` then you simply pay the points and they have the additional equipment.

Comment: Thanks - because I had the icon on a staff (left hand) it didn't seem possible to display the equipped weapon (all my chainswords are left handed and boltguns are two handed) and so I wasn't sure if it replaced it by necessity.